# Cannot see widgets and templates in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I want to use and extend some of widgets and themes of web app builder in arcgis.com or ArcGIS Online, but I can't see them when I click on web app builder button for developing app.

How can I solve this problem?

Is this problem due to my account or my browser or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extend the widgets and styles you need to be using the [Developer Edition of Web AppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/).  Once you have the application setup and registered, you can find the source code of the widgets in the \client\stemapp\widgets folder (2D) and \client\stemapp3d\widgets (3D).  Here is more information on [creating themes](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/create-a-theme.htm) and [configuring widgets](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/widget-overview.htm).

Comment: Must we have Developer Edition of Web AppBuilder for using widgets in ArcGIS Online?
I think Developer Edition of Web AppBuilder is necessary for developing widgets and themes in Portal for ArcGIS. Am I Right?

Comment: From your question about extending the widgets and themes I took that as the need to modify the widgets source code.  That is for both ArcGIS Online and Portal for ArcGIS web maps.  Think of it this way, the Web AppBuilder is simply a shell, and the web map/services it consumes which fill it up come from ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS.  All of the content is coming in from the data on a web map, this is also what is used by the widgets in regards to data sources.  The application itself is just the shell, and for Web AppBuilder, both Portal and ArcGIS Online are used to supply data.